# Loop and add Specific Categories and Products Images

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, page-template

Thanks to [Rafael Marques](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/25562/rafael-marques), I have a list of Products and Categories organized based on different created categories. I also have 5 different Custom Page Templates. Now I would like to display the product images (only images, because this is just an image gallery) in each of the pages. The page template looks like:

```
<?php 
/**
Template Name: Gallery Art
*/
get_header(); ?>
<div id="scrool" class="clearfix">
    <div class="gal item">
        <a class="group4" href="img/gallery/Beauty/Beauty 1.jpg">
            <img src="img/gallery/Beauty/gal/Beauty 1.jpg" alt="Ghazal Photo" width="231" height="149" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

How can I do this based on categories? For example, let's say I have a page called Art and powered based on Art_Page template. How can I add all images (products) to only this template, which is categorized under artCat?

Comment: How do you add the images to a page? Image gallery or featured images?

Comment: I think it is better to be Image Gallery.Can you please let me know what is the different between them?

Comment: Let's focus on your main question please. Different questions you can open separated.

Answer (score 1):

In your functions.php

```
function show_all_thumbs() {
    global $post;
    $post = get_post($post);
    $images =& get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&output=ARRAY_N&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&post_parent='.$post->post_parent);
    if($images) {
        foreach( $images as $imageID => $imagePost ){
            unset($the_b_img);
            $the_b_img = wp_get_attachment_image($imageID, 'thumbnail', false);
            $thumblist .= '<a href="'.get_attachment_link($imageID).'">'.$the_b_img.'</a>';
        }
    }
    return $thumblist;
}
```

In your page template file:

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'         => 'demo', // or whatever is called your custom post type
        'cat'               => 5, // or whatever is the "id" for your custom post type category
        'posts_per_page'    => 10
    )
);
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    echo show_all_thumbs();
endwhile;
endif;
```

Let us know please.

For different/extra questions which have nothing to do with this topic, please ask them separated, starting a new questions thread.

**Example for Featured Image version:**

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'         => 'demo', // or whatever is called your custom post type
        'cat'               => 5, // or whatever is the "id" for your custom post type category
        'posts_per_page'    => 10
    )
);
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Hi GRÁVUJ, Thanks for your help but I am not getting any images when I load the page.Can we do this through Feature Image?

Comment: yes, updated answer with another example code

Comment: Sorry man! but this is still not working! I followed every thing but I do not know why is not working JUST empty page! btway thanks for your help and comments!

Comment: have you checked the parameters? are they correct. in the above examples they have only example purpose. i can't know what do you have in your dev environment.